# Vuex - local variable assigned a mapState value, changing local variable also changes store variable?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Why does my original Vuex object get changed when I assign its value to a local variable and manipulate the local value? I can post my store.js if necessary.

I have something like this:

```
  data() {
    return {
      localObject: [],
    };
  },
computed: mapState(["storeObject"]), // main store object
  created() {
    this.localObject = this.storeObject;
    this.prepareData();
  },
methods: {
    prepareData() {
      this.localObject.forEach((event, i) => {
        delete event.artist_supporting;
        delete event.genre;
      });
      // console.log(this.storeObject); // why is this object getting changed by the localObject.forEach? 
    }
}
```

Here's the complete computed() block. If I console `this.eventsData` at the top of the computed value `calendarData()` it's complete as expected. But if I console `this.eventsData` at the bottom, before the return, it's altered as if I was manipulating it directly.

```
computed: {
    ...mapState(["loading", "eventsData"]),
    calendarData() {
      console.log(this.eventsData); // correct "complete" object
      let data = this.eventsData;
      data.forEach((event, i) => {
        delete event.artist_supporting;
        delete event.genre;
        delete event.venue;
        delete event.venue_city;
        delete event.venue_state;
        delete event.capacity;
        delete event.announce_date;
        delete event.onsale_date;
        delete event.promoter;
        delete event.business_unit;
        delete event.show_type;
        delete event.confirm_date;
        delete event.cancelled_date;
        delete event.status;

        event.venue_id = `event_${i}`;
        event.id = event.venue_id;
        event.title = event.artist_headliner;
        event.startDate = event.event_date;

        delete event.venue_id;
        delete event.artist_headliner;
        delete event.event_date;

        let date = new Date(event.startDate);
        let day = date.getDate();
        let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        if (day < 10) {
          day = "0" + day;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
          month = "0" + month;
        }
        event.startDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
      });
      console.log(this.eventsData); // edited object
      return data;
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because by doing `this.localObject = this.storeObject;` you are assigning the reference of `storeObject` to `localObject` which makes both variables point to the same memory. Mutating either of them will affect another. If you need to isolate the effect, you have to make a deep copy. The easiest way is to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)`:

```
this.localObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.storeObject))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you **Copy** the `state` object from the store, this can be achieved by using the spread operator:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState(["storeObject"])
}
```

See also the docs [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#object-spread-operator_).

Comment: Thank you. I tried the spread and had the same results. I added a little more information and my complete `computed: {}` block to my question.