# Vuex - transform store object without altering original

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to copy a store object for local transformation but my alteration function is changing the original store object also. I'm using `...mapState["storeObject"]`

This is basically what's happening:

```
state.storeOjb = "original value" 
this.local = storeOjb ;
this.local = "altered version of storeOjb"

storeOjb === "original value" // false -- why?
```

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example?

Comment: @Psidom I'll try to create a codepen. The code is pretty complex and I'm sure there is something else happening. I have 4 routes in the app, and they all use the same data, but some routes/pages need to alter the data. When I navigate to those "transformed data" pages and go back to one of the "virgin data" pages it's broken. It's like the altered version is getting committed to the store, but it isn't. This is a 10,000 node json object that's getting committed to the store and localStorage.

Comment: Can you try the solution provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62806129/4983450?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's your problem is. But you can remove the object mutation by

```
this.local = Object.assign({}, storeObj)
```

## Vue

In Vue JS, for local changes you can use computed property of the storeObj.

```
computed: {
  localValue: function() {
    return { ...storeObj, newChange: true }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It passed an object reference since your code `this.local = storeOjb`
When you change the value of `this.local`, `state.storeOjb` also changed.
So you may change your code like `this.local = storeOjb + ""`, so we can only copy the value but not object reference.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like it might work... except... storeObj is an object so I can't append a string to it. I tried `this.local = storeObj + ""` and got an error when I tried to transform the local.